# GTM Google Tag Manager: Set "page" in Virtual Page View Issue

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, tracking

How to track a virtual page view with GTM. Dozens of tutorials, checked them all and tried from scratch a couple of times. Issue: Page Path (aka "page") value in GA not set to what I defined in GTM.

Explanation: The page I want to track is technically one page (form.php), featuring a multi-step form. So, several html forms after each other. The end goal is that on the (successful) submit of each form a virtual pageview will be triggered. As the mechanic is based on jQuery, I plan to use a data layer push event as the trigger. Step by step:

1. **Defined a DataLayer variable in GTM** for the page path called `formID` and prior to the event (used as trigger) set the value, formatted as a relative path:

   `dataLayer.push({ 'formID':'/form-start' });`
2. **Set an event** with the name `formSubmit` as the trigger and trigger it with:

   `dataLayer.push({'event': 'formSubmit'});`
3. In the tracking ID variable as well as in the tag itself, I **set the Field Name `page` to the data layer variable** where the value of `formID` is stored

Testing in the console, both in the preview as well as in the published container, even after refresh, deleting cookies and much more, I get the following results:

In the `DataLayer` tab in the preview, I can see:

```
event: 'formSubmit',
formID: '/form-start'
```

In the `Variables` tab in the preview, I can see the tag fired, and for the Google Analytics settings and the Tracking ID:

```
fieldsToSet: [
    {fieldName: 'anonymizeIp', value: 'true'},
    {fieldName: 'page', value: '/form-start'},
    ...
```

However, in the `Variables` tab as well as in Google Analytics, `Page Path` is still `'/form.php'`.

Please, can anybody give me a hint what I am missing here? Any help very much appreciated.

---

**Edit: Screenshots attachements**

tag setup (hint: I added dp as a test, as I read in one forum to try the measurement protocol parameters)

[image: tag setup (hint: I added dp as a test, as I read in one forum to try the measurement protocol parameters)]

---

trigger configuration

[image: trigger configuration]

---

DataLayer variables when testing

[image: DataLayer variables when testing]

Comment: Are you able to provide a screenshot of how your tag is set up?

Comment: sure thing @vinoaj, done and thank you!

Comment: This looks pretty correct to me. Is `formID` set at the **same time** or **before** the `formSubmit` event fires? If the answer is no, then there is your problem.

Comment: @vinoaj found the issue - cannot explain but it seems I was not supposed to fill the Tracking ID field in the override settings as well. When I left it blank it worked. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after days, I found the issue. Still cannot explain why this is the case, but in the tag I had enabled `Enable overriding settings in this tag` and had enterend into the field `Tracking ID` below again the GA ID variable. Since I removed the variable and left the field blank, everything has been working.

Hope this is helpful to anybody who ever might experiencing same issues. Please, if anybody can explain why this is the case very happy to hear and learn.

Want to thank @Дмитро Булах for pointing me in the right direction with his answer. Thank you!

[image: Tag setup with empty GA ID field in overriding settings]

Answer (score 1):

The value of `Page Path` displayed in the Variables Tab will be the value of `window.location.pathname` regardless of your pushes to dataLayer. What you should check is that Goole analytics receives and tracks the desired value for `page`. To do that you may 1) check the value of `dp` parameter in the request to `www.google-analytics.com/collect` or 2) check the parameters of Analytics tag with [Tag Assistant Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) or 3) check the 'Top Active Pages' in the Google Analytics 
Real Time Report.